# How to include DNN Module into HTML Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'd like to insert several PayPal DNN modules into a different parts of a HTML table.

How can I do it?

The modules will need to have their settings accessible to customize the correct details etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new copy of the skin template you wish to use that includes the HTML table structure you want.

In each `td` element, you should create an empty `div` element with a unique `ID` attribute value, as well as a `runat="server"` attribute.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="TableRow1Column1Pane" runat="server"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="TableRow1Column2Pane" runat="server"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You'll then be able to select that new skin template, and drag and drop the PayPal modules into whatever table cells you wish.

Comment: What @Tim said. You you can't include other "modules" inside of a module. But you can customize the Skin, to change the Layout/Template and provide more "places" (panes) where a Module can go on a page.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I'll give that a go.